# Modificar a href

Tags: css

Estoy intentando modificar el contenido de este a `href`, para hacer que el tamaño `width` sea menor y quepa en el cuadrado.

El problema es que no encuentro manera de modificarlo. He probado con el nombre de la clase + a, pero no surte efecto.

```
<div class="botons_header">
  <div class="botons_header1">
    <a href="Usuaris/{{url_primer}}" class="buto_login_header">{{primer}}</a>
  </div>
  <div class="botons_header2">
    <a href="Usuaris/{{url_segon}}" class="buto_login_header">{{segon}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lee la sección de como preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, muchos no pueden ver las imágenes, intenta poner el código de lo que has realizado así es mas fácil ayudarte https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Actualizado con código

Comment: Según vi la imagen que habías puesto. En tus estilos no selecciones a la etiqueta `a`, en vez de eso indícale a la clase `buto_login_header` que tenga una propiedad `width` mas amplia por ejemplo `.buto_login_header{ width: 200px; }`

Comment: Agrega el código `CSS` a la pregunta, por favor.